# Why does my Tabstrip menu show all its content when the page loads?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, menu, load

My problem is that I was trying to use a TabStrip menu in my page, but when the page load for first time, the menu shows all the tabs' content in the first tab, then, when I select one of the tabs, everything looks ok.

[Here is a screenshot of my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiO9y.png)

Here is the design of the menu:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" >
  <div id="idTav">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist"  >
      <li><a href="#tab1" aria-controls="tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">General</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab2" aria-controls="tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Details</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab3" aria-controls="tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Top</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content" style="padding-top:10px">
      <div role="tabpanel"class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="panel-heading" data-for="panel1"><h3 class="text-primary">Information 1</h3></div>
          <div class="panel-body" data-for="panel1">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="PanelActualizarDireccion" runat="server">
              <ContentTemplate>
                <fieldset>
                  this is tab1
                </fieldset>
              </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div role="tabpanel"class="tab-pane active" id="tab2">
        <div role="tabpanel"class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="panel-heading" data-for="panel1"><h3 class="text-primary">Information2</h3></div>
            <div class="panel-body" data-for="panel1">
              <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                  <fieldset>
                    this is tab 2
                  </fieldset>
                </ContentTemplate>
              </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div role="tabpanel"class="tab-pane active" id="tab3">
        <div role="tabpanel"class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="panel-heading" data-for="panel1"><h3 class="text-primary">Information3</h3></div>
            <div class="panel-body" data-for="panel1">
              <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                  <fieldset>
                    this is tab 3
                  </fieldset>
                </ContentTemplate>
              </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have nothing in the backend code yet.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Is your tab initialization done in jquery `document ready` function?

In that case you can have the tab containers as hidden div. Then on page ready make the tab visible that you want to show. What Library are you using to render the tab?